# Replacing curly braces { } in a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I did a group by to concatenate strings in a dataframe in Python. It gave a Series output with curly braces. I'm trying to replace the braces using Replace function. It is not working. This is what I tried.

```
df_final['Word'].replace(to_replace=["{"],value="",inplace=True)
```

Comment: can you post the code for contatenation? I am just trying to make sure whether it can be avoided there itself. Otherwise, you can try `df['Word']=df['Word'].str.replace('{','')`

Comment: replace return a copy of the changed string, it does not change the object itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, need `regex=True` to [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) for replace substrings and if necessary add both braces:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'Word':['aa {sss}','{s}', 'sas']})
print (df_final)
       Word
0  aa {sss}
1       {s}
2       sas


df_final['Word'].replace(to_replace="[{}]",value="", regex=True, inplace=True)
print (df_final)
     Word
0  aa sss
1       s
2     sas
```

Another similar solution with [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df_final['Word'] = df_final['Word'].str.replace("[{}]","")
print (df_final)
     Word
0  aa sss
1       s
2     sas
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like you need

```
df_final['Word'] = df_final['Word'].str.replace("{", "").str.replace("}", "")
```

Comment: Try this,
df_final['Word'] = df_final['Word'].str.replace("{|}", "")